# Menu Navigation using ViewFlipper in android?

Tags: android, viewflipper

i have one listview contain menu based on the selected item in listview i want to display new view(add or edit or delete) that is defferent add.xml or edit.xml or delete.xml file.I want to show below like this.Also how to back in to main menu from child view.

i tried using  tag using ViewFlipper.showNext() but it display only add view all the time.

Thanks in advance..

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, Can you post your xml layout ?

Comment: if user click on Add in listView it will display new view contains add details, like wise edit and delete.

Answer (score 0):

You are using different xml. Then why can't you set this as different intent, so it will be easy to navigate. 
Anyway `viewFlipper.showNext()` will only show the next child
You can use  `viewflipper.setDisplayedChild(whichChild)` to get the desired child